# Github: How do I keep clean branches for PRs while merging them locally?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I have a fork of a repository on Github.

I'm creating all sorts of little patches. For each patch I create a local branch and submit a PR.

Now I also need all these patches merged together for a local build which includes all of the features.

- Should I merge them into my local master? If so, where do I branch off in the future?
- Can I somehow base a new branch **B** (new code) on another branch **A** (adjusted buildsystem) I submitted a PR for, and still keep those separate? Meaning that I submit a PR for **B** without the contents of **A**, and **A** separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate branch and merge all your branches into it to do your local build. If you create more features or just update one of the branches, you can merge them to that branch too.

You could also use your local master to do that if you prefer so. Afterwards you can use `git checkout -b new-branch origin/master` to create new branches, which would use the master from the remote repository named origin as the base for the new branch.

It is not possible to create a pull request for just a part of the changes contained in a branch. So after merging A to B (or creating B based on A), the changes from A would also occur in the Pull request for B.

Answer (score 0):

When ever the changes are made in the master of github, sync has to be made to local master branch which is just a sync branch(never do any dev here)

```
Github -> master    Sync    to    Local  -> master
```

Case 1: New feature development

- Update the local master branch with parent
- Create a new branch out of local master branch `git checkout -b new-feature-a`
- Commit and push the changes to `new-feature-a`
- Raise a PR to `Github->master` from
  `new-feature-a`

Create a branch for individual contribution and better enhancements and schedule periodical builds on `Github->master`.

Case 2: Separate branch for build and master

- Create a new branch for builds `master-build` from `Github->master`
- All the changes merged to `Github->master` should be in sync with the `master-build` either PR wise or on periodical wise, depends on how frequent the build runs.

Separate branches keep the code simple. But dependent branches code should be available. In this case, `B` contains the changes from `A` and it has to sequential.

Dependent PRs should always be merged in this case.

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear to me. What exactly are the "master of github". Mine or upstream master? Also what is "parent of local master branch".